# Append category base/slug/word to url for certain categories only

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to append `/blog/` inbetween the home url and category/post title slugs for certain categories. This works fine. However it does not reflect in the category archive pages for those categories.

```
function custom_category_permalink($permalink, $post) {
    if (has_term(array(23, 34, 64), 'category', $post)) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit(home_url('/blog/' . $post->post_name));
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'custom_category_permalink', 10, 2);
```

For example a single post `website.com/news/post-1` becomes --> `website.com/blog/news/post-1` : This part works fine
However for the category archive `website.com/news/`it stays as --> `website.com/news/`

Would really appreciate some help if I can append the word blog to this as well so it reads `website.com/blog/news/`

Comment: You are using the `post_link` hook there, so you probably need to look for a corresponding hook for archive links. `post_type_archive_link` sounds like it might be relevant.